# Custom Post Type equivalent for "Posts Page" setting in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to setup a custom post type plugin in wordpress that allows for selecting a page that will produce the posts list in the same fashion as setting the "Posts page" setting so that when the url of the page is accessed it produces the custom post types archive page instead of the page content.

I have option for selecting the page to use setup and it uses the pages slug as the rewrite  slug for the custom post type, I just can't figure out how to get it to display the archive instead of the page content.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the WordPress [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), assuming you're using a custom post of type Foo, you want to put your archive code in `archive-foo.php`.

Comment: I am not trying to get it to display using a specific archive template, the default is fine. It is the ability to function like setting the wordpress "posts page" setting so that when the page is selected in the plugin option page going to the URL of the page produces the archive of the custom post type the same way wordpress does it for regular posts and the page you select as the "Posts Page"

Comment: So to clarify, you are already able to set your custom archive URL in the plugin options, you're just seeing a single custom post's content when you go to that URL? Did you set `has_archive` to true in your custom post type declaration?

Answer (score 0):

I have a working solution, there is probably a better solution but this work for top level pages. Basically I check to see if the slug for the page has changed and flush the rewrite rules if it has.

```
add_action( 'init', 'faqmgr_create_post_type' );
function faqmgr_create_post_type() {
    $options=get_option('faqmgr_options', array('faq_page'=>0, 'faq_slug'=>'faq'));
    $updated=false;
    $tpost=get_post( $options['faq_page'], OBJECT );
    if(is_null($tpost)){
        $options=array('faq_page'=>0, 'faq_slug'=>'faq');
    $updated=true;
        update_option('faqmgr_options', $options);
    }else{
        if($options['faq_slug']!=$tpost->post_name){
            $options['faq_slug']=$tpost->post_name;
            $updated=true;
        }
    }
    register_post_type( 'faq',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'FAQs' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'FAQ' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add FAQ' ),
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit FAQ' ),
                'new_item' => __( 'New FAQ' ),
                'view_item' => __( 'View FAQ' ),
                'search_items' => __( 'Search FAQs' ) 
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'exclude_from_search'=>true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => $options['faq_slug'],
            'with_front' => false
        ),
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'thumbnail'
        )
        )
    );

    if($updated=true;){
        flush_rewrite_rules( false );
    }

}
```